# How to set properties, classpath and project files to editable in android?

Tags: android, build, properties, classpath, target

I am trying to change the target build of my Android project from 3.2 to 1.6.
However I cannot change it from properties of the project directly. It keeps overwriting my choice.

I checked the solution of : [How to change target build on Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342739/how-to-change-target-build-on-android-project)
He said that "turns out my properties, classpath and project files were set as unwritable which is why it didnt work, works now, thanks –"

However I don't know how to change such settings .. any idea ?

Comment: The problem is definetly in editing the properties of the project .. because I cannot as well set (is library) field of the project properties without being overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just double click on AndroidManifest.xml on package explorer, select the AndroidManifest.xml tab and change the x value of  line to desired sdk version.