# Why Eclipse don't understand Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT?

Tags: android

I install SDK for Android 4.4, create new app (manifest minSdkVersion=19 and targetSdkVersion=19), but this code don't work

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

}
```

[Screenshot](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/9253/27875755.10/0_8c1ac_41090561_L.png)

I'm sorry, I find my mistake. I change Project Build Target in Project's Properties to 19.

Answer (score 7):

You have to select Android 4.4 for your project if you haven't done so. Right click on top of the project->Properties->Android then check Android 4.4 if that is already there.

Answer (score 4):

Change you project's Build Target to Android 4.4 (19)

see - [How to change target build on Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342739/how-to-change-target-build-on-android-project)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio do the following:

1-File->project structure->Compile Sdk Version.

from there select the sdk version to latest so build.version_codes can find Kitkat or above.