# Cordova build: Please install Android target: "android-22". I dont want android-22. I want android-19 - what do I do?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, phonegap-build

I'm struggling with my phonegap setup and building my first app.

I created a hello1 project. I added the android project

> Platform android already added

Now when I run the cordova build, I get the error -

> Error: Please install Android target: "android-22"

I do not have android-22. I do have android-19. I want my project to be built with android-19. How can I make that happen?

I had android-22 which I uninstalled (for fixing a bigger problem). I do not understand which file should I be making a change in for this to work.
The `project.properties` in the project comes after this step and it automatically contains the target as android-22.

I have added my env variables correctly.
`C:\Users\user\android-sdks\platform-tools;C:\Users\user\android-sdks\tools`

It doesn't help. This is just part of a bigger problem that I'm trying to debug. Please help.

Comment: You need to change the targed sdk from 22 to 19 . What IDE are you using ? If eclipse, please check ;  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342739/how-to-change-target-build-on-android-project

Answer (score 24):

**For SDK 21** (`"android-21"`)

```
$ cordova platforms remove android
$ cordova platforms add android@3.7.1
```

**For SDK 22** (Android 4.1.1, `"android-22"`)

```
$ cordova platforms remove android
$ cordova platforms add android@4.1.1
```

More info: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/07/21/cordova-android-4.1.0.html

Answer (score 7):

Change these two. I din't try it for lower versions but this worked for me in upper versions

```
target=android-22<br>
```

This should be changed in two files like below:

```
target=android-19<br>
```

Location of the two files:

myApp/platforms/android/project.properties 
myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties

Answer (score 5):

I am using cordova 3.5.0 which by default has target sdk as 19.
You can install cordova 3.5.0 using

```
npm install -g cordova@3.5.0-0.2.6
```

For other versions of Cordova if you want to manually edit it you have to change this in AndroidManifest.xml file present in yourapplication/platfomrs/android.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar. I was using Cordova 5.0.0 and just realised that I get 22 as the default target. I will  change that will the command that you posted. Helps.

Comment: @Arvind accept the correct answer once you verify it :).

Answer (score 4):

My problem got solved after installing SDK Platform of Andriod 5.1.1 (API 22) from Andriod Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

- $ /Users/**username**/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
- Install Android 5.1.1 (API 22)
- $ cordova platforms add android@4.4.2
- $ cordova build --release android

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cordova platforms remove android
$ cordova platforms add android@3.7.1
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a specific input.