# Build using API-19 with cordova-android@4.1.1

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I have currently installed cordova using npm. the latest version of cordova-android i get is 4.1.1. I have created a project "cordova create" and added platform. When i try to build the build the project the build fails.

The reason is that the SDK that i have is only API-19(kitkat), bur it is expecting API-22. 
Is there any workaround to build my project with current API that I have?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade your sdk to 22 via the sdk manager and then change the target sdk in your manifest to 22. If you use eclipse, click Window -> Android SDK Manager, then check what you want to install under the 22 category and install. If you use Android Studio, you have a button for launching the sdk manager right from the toolbar:
[image]

If you have to use sdk 19 as target, use this link:
[Cordova build: Please install Android target: "android-22". I dont want android-22. I want android-19 - what do i do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028483/cordova-build-please-install-android-target-android-22-i-dont-want-android)

Comment: This should do it. `minsdk` has always been available. The option is hidden now. [Your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135185/how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers) You can also Google: [phonegap 4.0 android preferences minsdk](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap+4.0+android+preferences+minsdk)

Comment: Thanks for the link that you have provided. That helped me