# Ionic/Android Build Failed while downloading artifact builder.jar [Gradle]

Tags: java, android, gradle, ionic-framework

I'm not that experienced with Ionic and Android development so I thought I give it a try. I'm at the early stage at it but I want to debug it on my (android) phone (HTC One M8). But everytime when I try to build it i get the following error;

[image]

I'm, really out of idea's at the moment on how to fix this... Any of you have some suggestions?

What I already did;

- follow the instructions on http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html
- installed the HTC Sync manager and enabled USB debugging on my phone
- installed the correct SDK version/tools that my phone has (5.0.1)
- installed the Android Support/Google repositories (found out this might help too)

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix it with another workaround. What i did was try building it with ant instead of gradle with

```
cordova build android -- -ant
```

At first it went okay, but it could not build for SDK v23. I tried to change the sdk version in all manifests and config files. But that didn't do the trick either... I did some digging and found out you can add a platform of a specific SDK level; [Cordova build: Please install Android target: "android-22". I dont want android-22. I want android-19 - what do i do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028483/cordova-build-please-install-android-target-android-22-i-dont-want-android) (first answer).

After removing my old platform and adding the new one i ran the build android -- -ant command again and that did the trick!