# Ionic 2 use Firebase as a storage for the images from the camera

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, camera, firebase-storage

I want to use Firebase as a storage for my images that are taken from the camera. I don’t know how to send this pictures to Firebase. Can anyone send me a code how can I do that.

Thank you!

Comment: There are a few threads on SO that cover Ionic uploads, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018980/firebase-storage-v3-returning-multipart-body-does-not-contain-2-or-3-parts-on and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452489/uploading-image-to-firebase-storage-from-cordova-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just finished watching tutorial on this, kindly check these two videos on youtube, hope the videos would help you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpxHVrpfGgU
or 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZCy1AK7x4I

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I tied to upload my pictures according to the video but I have some error it says: “EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.”

Comment: On my link https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ag-smaCl1QJPg1ZoMHWw5WO_Vhtl , you have a picture from my code. I tried to make a file of the data file similar like on the video but it gives me another error “Cannot read property ‘files’ of undefined”.
I saw some forums there it says that you should process the file somehow so you’ll be able to upload it to firebase, I tried that but I can’t import the “fetch” function and I can’t use the function so I can process the file.

Thank you