# Cordova update/new project errors

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I need to install a plugin for cordova, specifically a crash tool. I have several options, and every time I try to install I get the warning that the version of Cordova-android is old and is deprecated, then the plugin get it to work precisely because of this problem.

The plugins I've tried are:

Crittercism for phonegap

appsee for cordova

Both in Android platform.

I have currently a project that "works" for the Cordova-android version 3.6.4 and the goal is to upgrade to version 5.1.1.

I've been looking at the documentation page of Cordova, where you say there are two ways to proceed, upgrade the project or create new current base and one copy the content of the current project in this. We will have to update plugins that give problems.

1) Upgrading from an existing project:

Which is best way is to remove the existing platform and add a (updated) New

```
cordova platform remove android 

cordova platform add android
```

and then add the contents of your asset/www folder if it is not already.

2) Create a new project updated

We create the new project

```
cordova create androidApp com.android.app AndroidApp
```

We went into the project folder created

```
cd androidApp
```

We installed the android platform

```
cordova platform add android
```

Having reached this point, in both cases I import the project in eclipse, in which two folders, MainActivity and CordovaLib imported.

I do not understand why creating the project with the above judgment calls "MainActivity" and not "AndroidApp". In both cases adds Android 6.0 libraries and gives me the following error:

```
Description Resource    Path Location Type The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\****\****\****\****\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\cordovalib.jar' MainActivity Build path Build Path Problem

The proyect cannot be build until path errors are resolved
```

Note: **** refer to directories that I want to hide.

Well, the problem is that I can not remove this error. I searched a lot about this problem here, and I've seen that occurs very often, the problem is that I have not been able to fix it in my case.

I tried to do the following:

I have compiled the project to generate cordovalib.jar through CordovaLib, but is not generated and remains missing. If I go to Project> properties > Java Build Path > Android has a red cross Dependencies error and library cordovalib.jar route in which puts the search you are missing.

I removed and relocated the library from my project> properties > Android> library as this in the new project must be done.

I've tried to do all Build Clean, Clean only CordovaLib and Build, Clean only MainActivity and build ...

I tried to close Eclipse and reopen it.

Version 3.6.4 of Cordova-Android works for me perfectly, but I need to put the plugin update. Currently I have the jdk 1.7 and I also tested with 1.8

You have the Android SDK 4.2.2, 4.4.2, 4.4w.2, 5.1.1, 6.0, and yet every time I go into eclipse I get another error, this time is:

Loading data dor Android 6.0 has Encountered a problem. Parsing data for android-23 failed.

If I change the target to android-22 also it gives me the same problem.

No longer I can do to fix it.

I would appreciate any advice on this topic

Thank you very much!

P.D: I have nodejs, git, sdk1.7 and 1.8, sdk for android. I use Eclipse for dev and a Tablet samsung galaxy tab as device.

Comment: Why not using android-studio instead of Eclipse?

Comment: I must to use eclipse :(

Comment: The android-cordova version (5.1.1 that you are trying to reach), do you know with which android SDK is it supposed to work? And hence, do you have the right android SDK to build?

Comment: I think that yes, but that would be the problem, i dont know... I have full update cordova 6.3.1 and then i want to install the cordova-android 5.1.1 version for the android platform. I have in my eclipse the SDK for 6.0, 5.1, 5.0, and lowers.. and i test it with jdk1.7 and jdk1.8. I use Eclipse JUNO

Comment: cordova-android 5.1.1 doesn't mean SDK android 5.1  I think (check that example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028483/cordova-build-please-install-android-target-android-22-i-dont-want-android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest release of Eclipse IDE, from the installer, select `Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers`. It contains the Eclipse IDE and its [Thym](https://www.eclipse.org/thym/) plugin, which supports Cordova development.

Comment: Changing eclipse JUNO for eclipse MARS2 fix my problem. THX Mickael & nyluje for all :D