# Is there an official way to use a specific android target with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to compile an Ionic 2 application on an Android SDK Target 19 (Android 4.4).

Ionic 2 use Cordova.

When I install cordova with NPM, the last version is installed (6.5). When I add an android platform the target is set by Cordova to android-22.

I read in several posts that there is a configuration key in the config.xml which allow to force the Android target.

So I wrote this in my plugin.xml :

```
  <platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>
  </platform>
```

When I build, the target remain 22 !

I read on [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028483/cordova-build-please-install-android-target-android-22-i-dont-want-android) that we have to edit some files generated by cordova :

- /platforms/android/project.properties
- /platforms/android/AndroidManfiests.xml
- /platforms/android/CordovaLib/project.properties

In this file, I replaced all the target=android-XX by android-19.
I don't like this solution because all this files are generated by Cordova, so I haven't to edit them !

The only solution I found is given in the same post : install an old cordova (cordova version 3.5.0-0.2.7). This version come with Android-19 as default version.

So my question is : *Is it possible to use the last cordova with an android target 19 ?*

When I read the cordova documentation, I think that answer to this question is "YES". But how to do it ? Why changing targetSdkVersion in plugin.xml haven't any effect on files generated by Cordova ?

Comment: Oh.. alright. I will delete the answer. I guess the only option is setting the required cordova-android version 3.5

Comment: Did you test this `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />` in your config.xml?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I add this in my config.xml, cordova still try to compile for android-23... I added it in <widget> and in <platform name="android">...

Comment: Did you find answer? I have this same issue today