# Changing Android build target in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android project in Eclipse that has targeted Android 2.2 for many years but now I want to use some newer features that are only available in later versions of Android, e.g., 4.xx

There is a Stack Overflow question on how to change the build target...

[How to change target build on Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342739/how-to-change-target-build-on-android-project)

. . but my selection in the box on the right that they mention only goes to 3.2.   How do I increase my options to newer versions on Android?

Comment: Download new SDK versions in the SDK Manager. Also, bear in mind that official Eclipse support has ended, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio - the now official IDE for Android development has a handy import feature for making Eclipse projects work.

As CommonsWare above mentioned, it might behoove yourself to make the switch.

[image]

It recently hit its 2.1.1 stable release: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: So I took your advice and now I can't get Android Studio to work [link]{http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304822/android-studio-newbie-clean-project-crashes)

Answer (score 0):

Install Higher version packages , Go to Android SDK Manager-> Select Version-> Install. Keep in mind Eclipse support has been ended, Use Android Studio.

Check Link to know how to install packages- (http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Eclipse-and-Setup-ADT)